# Materialize.css Dynamic Modals + Ajax glitching out

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, materialize

I've recently started using materialize.css in my projects and it's been great. However, in my latest website, I tried creating dynamic modals with ajax gathered data.

The modals generate correctly but a weird glitch appears. After generating the modal it should automatically open, but it only opens after you click three times the trigger and it generates three modals (you can test it [here](http://gos-db.com/GoSDB/)).

Here's the code:

```
$(".champion-card").click(function() {
    var champion = $(this).find(".card-title").html();
    var champion_id = champion_id = champion.replace(/ /g,"-").replace('.', "")+'Modal';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getdata.php',
        data: { scripts: champion },
        success: function(data) {
            $("body").append('<div id="'+champion_id+'" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"><h4>Scripts - '+champion+'</h4><div class="row"><ul class="list">'+data+'</ul></div></div></div>');
        }
    });
    $('#'+champion_id).modal('open');
    $('#'+champion_id).modal({
        complete: function() { 
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

'getdata.php' only echoes a text containing the data posted.

http://materializecss.com/modals.html says opening a modal is done by the code:

```
$('#modal1').modal('open');
```

If I remember correctly, before it was .leanModal(), but I don't think that's a cause. The frustrating thing is that it opens after 3 clicks, generating 3 modals with the same id.

I couldn't find what's wrong and I though maybe the community can help. The are no errors received.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't. Undefined function.

Comment: Yeah, that was a wrong plugin, sorry. Can you define the modal before you open?

Comment: I added the modal open code in the success function and now it requires only 2 clicks.

Comment: Can you also replace the order of modal functions? call modal('open') after you define the modal.

Comment: It worked by defining it before using `$('#'+champion_id).modal();`.

Thanks a lot!